# Aginity Workbench for puredata systems for analytics Identifier error

Tags: mysql, sql, netezza, aginity

This process is to create a new table and ingest data into Netezza database. The code was running fine until last week. When I ran with the new data, it started erroring out. I tried with the old data as well. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for the help! Below is the code.

```
ERROR [42000] ERROR:  'CREATE TABLE INTER.DETAILS_NEW AS 
SELECT
EMP_ID, 
EMPLOYEE_NAME

from external 'C:\2018\Sep files\Interminations.txt' 
(
EMP_ID NVARCHAR(10), 
EMPLOYEE_NAME NVARCHAR(100)
)
USING 
(
encoding 'internal'
datestyle 'MDY'
datedelim '/'
DELIMITER '\t' 
REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
maxerrors 10000
)'
error            ^ found "CREATE" (at char 9) expecting `DELETE' or `INSERT' or `SELECT' or `UPDATE' or `WITH'
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. This SQL will not load data, it has explain to start with. Does `INTER.DETAILS_NEW` table exist? If it does your query will fail.

Comment: No, this table does not exist. Its a create table statement and I did explain to see the error below as Aginity truncates error message.